# uiimagepickercontroller opens but not displaying images ios 8

Tags: ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, ios8

I have an application in which i have to open image picker, it work fine in all devices and all iOS upto iOS 7.1.

But now i have iPad device with 8.0 beta 4 in this gallery opens but it doesn't display images although folder names are there. Even when i tap on blank white image from the gallery picker.It display the original image set in my imageView.

Here is some of my code ....

UIImagePickerController *pickerPhoto = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
pickerPhoto.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary & UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
pickerPhoto.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:pickerPhoto animated:YES];

I notice that my application is in compatible mode for iPad ,other universal app works perfectly.

here is some screen shots

1)http://tinypic.com/r/1z5rvid/8

2)http://tinypic.com/r/2d76o9/8

Comment: Did you found a fix for this? Is happening to my app in some phones. If you found a solution I'll be glad to know.

Comment: Have the same problem with iOS 9 on ipad air, does anyone know how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this problem in ios 8 Bcz of in iOS 8 open gallery only Universal Application please refer apple official document

Comment: ya thanks for this but i want to image picker as normal as previous i have.

Comment: It happened to me in 1st beta version of iOS 8 but it didn't occur after the next version of beta iOS8.